# Is the centralizer $Z_G(A)=\{g\in G| a g= g a\}$ of a finite $A\subset G$ connected for a connected compact Lie group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a connected compact Lie group, consider the left/right action on itself.
For any **finite** $A\subset G$, consider the centralizer
$Z_G(A):=\{g\in G| a g= g a\}$.

Q: is $Z_G(A)$ a connected subgroup?

Answer (score 6):

What is $A$? Is it a subset? Is it a subgroup? Is it an abelian subgroup?

In the first two cases, the answer is no: the centralizer of the binary icosahedral group inside $SU(2)$ is $Z(SU(2))=\mathbb Z/2$. If $A$ is required to be abelian, then it again doesn't work: consider a subgroup of order two inside $SO(3)$. Its centraliser is $
\mathbb Z/2
\ltimes S^1$.

If $A$ is abelian and $G$ is also assumed to be simply connected, then it might be the case that the centralizer is always connected, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Concerning the "simply connected" question, this only makes sense if $G$ is assumed semisimple.   Though I'm not sure how far the compact Lie group literature goes, I also suspect that centralizers in that case are connected (in the standard topology).  This is certainly true in the often-parallel case of a semisimple algebraic group over an algebraically closed field when you are given a *semisimple* element (automatic for a compact Lie group), by Steinberg and Springer.   There too the (Zariski) connectedness may fail when the group is not simply connected.

Comment: For the case where $A$ is Abelian and $G$ is simply connected, if $\alpha$ is a short root of $\mathrm{Spin}_7$ (or whatever the compact form is called), then I think that the centraliser of $\alpha^\vee(-1)$ is $\mathrm{SU}_2 \times \mathrm{SU}_2 \times \mathrm{PU}_2$.  If that is true, and if $\beta$ is "a root in $\mathrm{PU}_2$", then the centraliser of $A = \langle\alpha^\vee(-1), ((1/2)\beta^\vee)(-1)\rangle$ is $\mathrm{SU}_2 \times \mathrm{SU}_2 \times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.  (I'm being a bit vague because, as @JimHumphreys points out, I'm actually thinking of algebraic groups.)